# Shouldn't be this "=+" a syntax error?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

Recently I was trying to use the following code:

```
int number = 4;
number += other_variable;//2
...
printf("Number:%d\n",number);//-->6
```

but I had an error typing and instead I've got this code:

```
int number = 4;
number =+ other_variable;//2
...
printf("Number:%d\n",number);//-->2
```

Apparently this compiled with `gcc 4.7.3` and `gcc 4.4.3` and the result was as a normal assignment operator. The **question** is: Shouldn't be this a syntax error?

Comment: The downvotes and marks are a bit harsh. The OP didn't know it was a unary plus operator.

Comment: They are not a bit harsh, they are misanthropy.

Comment: And btw I do not see how is this duplicated of `What's the unary plus operator do?`

Comment: FWIW it's the same thing with the `var --> 0` "operator" that is actually `var-- > 0`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No - this is being parsed as:

```
number = +other_variable;
```

i.e. you have assignment and a unary + operator. You're reading it as `=+` but it's two separate operators, `=` and `+`.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's just a null op.

```
number = +other_variable;
number = 0 + other_variable;
```

As a complement to these operations, which negate:

```
number =- other_variable;
number = -other_variable;
number = 0 - other_variable;
```

Comment: -1, that's certainly not what it's doing, it is not computing the absolute value of its operand.

Comment: @unwind Just poorly worded from me, I didn't mean it changed sign.

Comment: @molbdnilo Just poorly worded from me, I didn't mean the `+` changed sign or that the `-` forced a negative sign.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are two separate operators.

`number = (+other_variable);`

The unary + operator when applied to a basic data type, as far as I know, doesn't do anything other than return the original value. It can be overloaded however.

It is the counterpart to unary - operator, which inverts the sign.

`number = (-other_variable);`

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a syntax error.

It's the same analogous to `a=-b;` - you can do `a=+b;` too. It has no effect to do that (for built-in types, objects you have defined `operator+()` for could of course do something funky here), but it's perfectly valid C code.